# How to make qt designer custom QOpenGLWidget widget background be transparent?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, transparent, qtopengl

I have create a custom qt designer widget which inherit from QOpenGLWidget. Everything is fine except I cannot get the widget background transparent.

**Is there a way to fix this issue?**

```
void MyOpenGl::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}

void MyOpenGl::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //gluPerspective(45, (float)w/h, 0.01, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //gluLookAt(0,0,5,0,0,0,0,1,0);
}

void MyOpenGl::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f( 0.0,  0.5, 0);
    glEnd();
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are clearing it with full opaque black color, have you tried a transparent color (alpha = 0)?

Comment: yes, tried alpha=0 and does not work

Answer (score 0):

Do not call glClear() in your MyOpenGL::paintGL() function with GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, that will make to rewrite the entire color buffer to the color set by glClearColor(). You can even omit it completely.